# My intellisense doesn't seem to work any more in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I noticed it never works any more. For example I have the following code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    // [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel a)
    {
        a.ResetPassword.
        MembershipService.ResetPassword();
        return View(l);
    }
```

When typing the line a.ResetPassword. I don't receive any prompts. Same for many other times when I type. The above is just one example of many. Any ideas on what could be wrong and why it doesn't work any more?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the database and forcing it to regenerate? You should also get Visual Assist X, the intellisense in that is much better (and faster).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Intellisense does not work for any of my code at all. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages. 
Ensure that the checkboxes in the Statement Completion section are actively checked (not grayed out).